# In systemd service file, how to correctly specify dependency on dbus

Tags: systemd

For my service,  I have:

```
#cat my.service
[Unit]  
Description=My Service  
After=dbus.service
Requires=dbus.service  
...
```

Some time i see that my service fails to get dbus connection
  (dbus_bus_get_private() fails without any error msg).
  one possibility i think is that dbus is not fully initialized.
  From above service file config, i understand when i start my service,
  dbus service is started 1st and then my service.
  but i am not sure if my service start step is delayed until dbus is
  fully up , initialized and running and ready to accept conections.
is there a way to specify this in my service file.

For ex, for systemd-networkd,service, i see it specify  like :

```
#On kdbus systems we pull in the busname explicitly, because it  
#carries policy that allows the daemon to acquire its name.  
Wants=org.freedesktop.network1.busname   
After=org.freedesktop.network1.busname
```

Can i use same (specifying After/Wants on a dbus name) ?
Appreciate your help on this.
Thanks